# Targeting specific values from JSON API and inserting into Postgresql, using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Right now i am able to connect to the url api and my database. I am trying to insert data from the url to the postgresql database using psycopg2.  I dont fully understand how to do this, and this is all i could come up with to do this.

```
import urllib3
import json
import certifi
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import Json


http = urllib3.PoolManager(
    cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
    ca_certs=certifi.where())
url = '<API-URL>'
headers = urllib3.util.make_headers(basic_auth='<user>:<passowrd>')
r = http.request('GET', url, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))


def insert_into_table(data):

    for item in data['issues']:
        item['id'] = Json(item['id'])

    with psycopg2.connect(database='test3', user='<username>', password='<password>', host='localhost') as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            query = """
                INSERT into
                     Countries
                    (revenue)
                VALUES
                    (%(id)s);
            """
            cursor.executemany(query, data)

        conn.commit()


insert_into_table(data)
```

So this code give me a `TypeError: string indices must be integers` on  `cursor.executemany(query, data)`

So i know that json.loads brings back a type object and that json.dumps brings a type string . I wasn't sure which one i should be using.  and i know i am completely missing something on how im targeting the 'id' value, and inserting it into the query.

Also a little about the API, it is very large and complex and eventually i'll have to go down multiple trees to grab certain values, here is an example of what i'm pulling from.

I am trying to grab "id" under "issues" and not "issue type"

```
{
  "expand": "<>",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 50,
  "total": 13372,
  "issues": [
    {
      "expand": "<>",
      "id": "41508",
      "self": "<>",
      "key": "<>",
      "fields": {
        "issuetype": {
          "self": "<>",
          "id": "1",
          "description": "<>",
          "iconUrl": "<>",
          "name": "<>",
          "subtask": <>,
          "avatarId": <>
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, extract `ids` into a list of tuples:

```
ids = list((item['id'],) for item in data['issues'])
# example ids: [('41508',), ('41509',)]
```

Next use the function [extras.execute_values():](http://psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values)

```
from psycopg2 import extras

query = """
    INSERT into Countries (revenue)
    VALUES %s;
"""
extras.execute_values(cursor, query, ids)
```

> Why I was getting type errors?

The second argument of the function [executemany(query, vars_list)](http://psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany) should be a sequence while `data` is an object which elements cannot be accessed by integer indexes.

> Why to use `execute_values()` instead of `executemany()`?

Because of performance, the first function executes a single query with multiple arguments, while the second one executes as many queries as arguments.

Note, that by default the third argument of `execute_values()` is a list of tuples, so we extracted `ids` just in this way.

If you have to insert values into more than one column, each tuple in the list should contain all the values for a single inserted row, example:

```
values = list((item['id'], item['key']) for item in data['issues'])

query = """
    INSERT into Countries (id, revenue)
    VALUES %s;
"""
extras.execute_values(cur, query, values)
```

Comment: that worked, but can you maybe explain the answer a bit and why i was getting type errors?

Comment: If i were to add another value, lets say `INSERT into table (title, revenue)  VALUES (%s, %s)` and then add the key value by doing `keys= list((item['key'],) for item in data['issues'])` then creating a variable `result = [ids, keys]` would i be able to pass 'result' instead of 'ids' in the `execute_values()` function to pass 'id' in the title column and 'keys' into the revenue column?

Comment: When I make those changes, i get this error `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: INSERT has more expressions than target columns` is this because of the sole placeholder `%s`? i realize that `execute_many()` allows for only one placeholder, so does this have to do with my actual table schema?

Comment: No I have that in my sql statement

Comment: Oh got it, accidentally put parenthesis around the %s placeholder, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get just the id and insert it into your table, you should try

```
ids = []
for i in data['issues']:
     ids.append(i['id'])
```

Then you can pass your `ids` list to you `cursor.executemany` function.

Comment: so `cursor.executemany(query, ids)`? along with the changes you made?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is not in the way you are parsing your JSON, it occurs when you try to insert it into your table using `cursor.executemany()`.

`data` is a single object, Are you attempting to insert all of the data your fetch returns into your table all at once? Or are you trying to insert a specific part of the data (**a list of issue IDs**)?

You are passing `data` into your `cursor.executemany` call. `data` is an object. I believe you wish to pass `data.issues` which is the list of issues that you modified.

If you only wish to insert the ids into the table try this:

```
def insert_into_table(data):

    with psycopg2.connect(database='test3', user='<username>', password='<password>', host='localhost') as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            query = """
            INSERT into
                 Countries
                (revenue)
            VALUES
                (%(id)s);
            """
            for item in data['issues']:
               item['id'] = Json(item['id'])
               cursor.execute(query, item['id')

            conn.commit()


insert_into_table(data)
```

If you wish keep the efficiency of using `cursor.executemany()` You need create an array of the IDs, as the current object structure doesn't arrange them the way the `cursor.executemany()` requires.

Comment: Okay that does make sense, now I'm getting an error saying the the Json object `item['id']` in the executemany function is not "iterable"

Comment: note that `execute()` and `executemany()` take different arguments. If you want to use `executemany()` you need to create the array of id's that you will pass to the function yourself. Does that make sense?